# Using systemd sockets with .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, systemd

I have installed a .NET Core application on my Ubuntu server, and it is running fine both when I run it manually and when I set it up as a systemd service. However, since the application is being run through an nginx web server, and I would like to only start the application when a user accesses it, I tried setting it up with a systemd socket so that the corresponding service only starts when the socket receives a notification from nginx. In this scenario, the application is not working and giving an error when it happens. Is there a way to set up socket-based activiation for .NET Core applications in Linux? I want to emphasize that the same service works fine when it's not activated by the socket. Below is the error I'm receiving, and the systemd units.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
No XML encryptor configured. Key {1c6b8e72-67bd-4653-b656-76f9dd136ee3} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
```

---

```
ercot.service
[Unit]
Description=ERCOT trade uploader daemon
Requires=ercot.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
# the specific user that our service will run as
User=www-data
Group=www-data
# another option for an even more restricted service is
# DynamicUser=yes
# see http://0pointer.net/blog/dynamic-users-with-systemd.html
RuntimeDirectory=ercot
WorkingDirectory=/srv/netcore/ercot
ExecStart=/srv/netcore/ercot/DashboardWebServer
# ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
TimeoutStopSec=5
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Unit]
Description=ERCOT trade uploader socket
```

---

```
ercot.socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/ercot.sock
# Our service won't need permissions for the socket, since it
# inherits the file descriptor by socket activation
# only the nginx daemon will need access to the socket
SocketUser=www-data
SocketGroup=www-data
# Optionally restrict the socket permissions even more.
# SocketMode=600

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Relevant Google searches bring up this error with IIS but that is obviously not relevant for this situation. Thanks!

https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/net-core/using-an-in-memory-repository-keys-will-not-be-persisted-to-storage-asp-net-core-under-iis/

Comment: The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` bits are warnings, not errors (they are saying that they can't do encryption on Linux to hide things even from `root`, that's expected). What's the actual error you are seeing? Are you using `.UseSystemd()` when building the host?

Comment: Hmmm. Was not aware those are warnings. Checked the journalctl logs for both ercot.socket and ercot.service and those were the only messages out of the ordinary. The only other error is that the web browser is returning a 504 Gateway Time-out. Maybe indicating the socket isn't communicating with the service properly? Or with nginx?

Comment: Here is the relevant nginx error log.

2021/05/12 18:31:22 [error] 16327#16327: *8475 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 199.185.131.171, server: kramericaindustries.hopto.org, request: "GET /private/ercot HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/ercot.sock/private/ercot", host: "kramericaindustries.hopto.org", referrer: "http://kramericaindustries.hopto.org/private/ercot/Awards"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my question was sort of incorrect. The application does not support socket activation so that's why it wasn't working. Instead the solution I came up with uses a socket proxy to achieve this with systemd-socket-proxyd being the app to use. Here are the three systemd units I made.

```
ercot-proxy.socket
[Unit]
Description=ERCOT trade uploader proxy socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/ercot-proxy.sock
SocketUser=www-data
SocketGroup=www-data

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

---

```
ercot-proxy.service
[Unit]
Description=ERCOT trade uploader proxy service

BindsTo=ercot-proxy.socket
After=ercot-proxy.socket

Wants=ercot.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-socket-proxyd 127.0.0.1:42222
```

---

```
ercot.service
[Unit]
Description=ERCOT trade uploader daemon
BindsTo=ercot-proxy.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/srv/netcore/ercot
ExecStart=/srv/netcore/ercot/DashboardWebServer
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The application doesn't support socket activation"?  I was wondering if this is possible with .net 6 without any other apps like you did with the proxy.

Comment: I simply mean this is a small, local app a contractor wrote, and AFAICT the only way to connect to it is through an HTTP connection. It's just how the contractor wrote it and told us to connect to it. I was under the mistaken impression that you could connect to any app with sockets regardless of how it was written. FWIW I ditched socket activation for this app because it was too clunky.